# Python - How to check for usb keyboard?

Tags: python-2.7, keyboard, raspberry-pi, raspbian

Is there any way to have a check that a usb keyboard is attached?
I'm new to both programming and python so I apologize if this is a dumb question.

Here's what I would like to happen:

```
if(usb_keyboard_attached == true):
    string1 = raw_input("Enter Text ")

maincode
```

I am using Python 2.7 and intend to run the script on a Raspberry Pi.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about detecting that it is a USB keyboard (or any type of keyboard for that matter), but it seems like you're just looking to make sure that this is interactive. If that's the case, you can use:

```
import sys
if sys.stdin.isatty():
    string1 = raw_input("Enter text ")
```

Comment: Your solution is not working for me. Does this differentiate between keyboard and mouse?

Comment: This does not check if there is a keyboard/mouse attached. It simply makes sure that the user can input through standard in (i.e. typing something at the console). I'm not sure if you can check for a keyboard in pure Python, but I did come across this one time [link](http://www.mattfischer.com/blog/?p=182) and it might be useful.